# CSS Change Class Style Admin Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a status page, which bascially says if a service is online or offline. I am using a css class on the div tags to make them look different (one red one green). I was looking at making an admin page were I can log in and change the class on the div with javascript onclick. It is basic code but works fine

```
<script>
function toggleClass(el){
if(el.className == "class1"){
el.className = "class2";
} else {
el.className = "class1";
}
}
</script>
<div class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
<div class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
```

I want  the changes I make on the admin.php page to effect the index.php, I cant have the index.php have the JS as people would just click and change the status. Is there an easy solution for this? I do have access to mysql and PHP if needed, any advice?

Comment: use addClass , removeClass

Comment: I don't know what you expected from PHP, but PHP just outputs what you put in. It doesn't know, or care about, CSS. Stick with JS here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save the status into mysql and check with php. so you don't need js for that.
create a function in your adminPanel to set the status.

If you have access to websockets use them to update the status on the fly.
otherwise create an interval which will automatically update the status every ... 5 seconds or something. The users don't want to reload the page every few seconds to get update.
also show the time when the status was updated the last time.